# Вывод объектов с уникальным полем

Tags: коллекции, сортировка, java, scanner

Есть класс Студент и отсортированный список с 10 объектами (поля вводятся с консоли в формате id-оценка). Если есть несколько записей с одинаковыми id, то программа должна выбрать только одну запись с максимальной оценкой и вывести список объектов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью чего это сделать.

```
 public class Student implements Comparable {

private int idSt;
private int score;

public Student(int id, int sc) {
    idSt = id;
    score = sc;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public int getIdStudent() {
    return idSt;
}

public String toString() {
    return idSt + "-" + score;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    Student tmp = (Student) obj;
    if (this.score > tmp.score) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.score < tmp.score) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
public class SortScore {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> st = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("[-\\n]");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        st.add(new Student(a, b));
    }

    Collections.sort(st);            
    System.out.println(st);     
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

См. интерфейс [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) и его реализации.

Comment: Там же не допускаются дубли ключей, ну это если вводить ключ-id, значение-оценка. А нужно, чтоб в списке было все, а выводились только поля объектов с уникальным id...

Comment: @leyla Что вам мешает хранить весь список и отдельно Map с максимальными значениями? Можете также хранить Map<Integer, Set<Student>>, и выбрать в качестве Set реализацию TreeSet со своим компаратором для сортировки по убыванию, тогда первый элемент всегда будет с максимальным значением.